Send CSRF token with PUT request by fetch in javascript
    fetch("/edit_post", {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            post_id: post_id,
            new_message: new_message,
        })
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            message_div.innerHTML = new_message;
        }
        else{
            message_div.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occured";
        }
    })

I am getting Forbidden (CSRF token missing.) error with above code, how do i send csrf token in fetch?
I kinda don't want to include the csrf token in the  of the html page if possible.
